# Función con SQL Server para devolver una existencia

Tags: sql-server, mssql

Intento realizar una función para validar la existencia de un dni.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ValidarDNI_v2]
(declare @DNI   VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE @validacion int
IF exists  (select COUNT(*) from TABLA WHERE  DNI=  @DNI) 

set @validacion =  1 
else
set @validacion =  0
RETURN @validacion
END
```

El tema es que siempre devuelve '0'.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar algunos datos de ejemplo? Lee [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que esa función siempre debería de regresar 1 porque el `SELECT COUNT(*)` siempre regresa una fila cuando no hay `GROUP BY`. La función `EXISTS()` está diseñada para revisar si existen filas, por lo tanto no se requiere una función de agregado dentro de esta función (a menos de que se requiera para una cláusula `HAVING`).

La función tal como está no se podría compilar, pero podría quedar de manera muy simple de esta forma.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ValidarDNI_v2]
(
    @DNI   VARCHAR(20)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE DNI = @DNI)  
                    THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0 
                END;
END
```